# Vertically centering with Flex, set a height, used Align-items, still not centering

Tags: css, flexbox, center, centering

I've read the techniques but after an hour and a half I can't figure out what's wrong.
Am I missing a position?
Why won't the text center vertically?

```css
.subscribe-btn {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0.5em;
  width: 290px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#4968b0, #3d559e);
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: outset;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.subscribe-btn a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="subscribe-btn">
    <a href="https://www.bridgetodata.org/register">Subscribe to [WEBSITE NAME]</a>
</div>
```

I've been using combinations of aligning in both the parent and child, trying different displays in the parent and child.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so first of all you should not be using a `div` at all for a link you want to look like a button. You only need the  tag that you will style to look like a button. Having the `div` be a part of the button in this case is needless and not semantic. So get rid of that by applying the button class to the  element.

```html
<a class="subscribe-btn" href="https://www.bridgetodata.org/register">Subscribe to [WEBSITE NAME]</a>
```

Then you can simply combine the styles and add `align-items: center` to the styles and you will get what you are looking for. Since you are using flex, you can also get rid of `text-align: center`.

```css
.subscribe-btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0.5em;
  width: 290px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#4968b0, #3d559e);
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: outset;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="subscribe-btn" href="https://www.bridgetodata.org/register">Subscribe to [WEBSITE NAME]</a>
```

But honestly unless you need all the buttons the exact same size, it would probably be better to not use flexbox at all and instead set `display: inline-block` and use padding instead of explicit height/width. Also use `rem` or `em` units instead of `px` units for the font-size and the padding. Like this:

```css
.subscribe-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#4968b0, #3d559e);
  border-style: outset;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<a class="subscribe-btn" href="https://www.bridgetodata.org/register">Subscribe to [WEBSITE NAME]</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You would need `align-items: center;` instead of `justify-content`.

You can get rid of justify-content since you are centrering horizontally using `text-align: center;`

Comment: He needs to not be using a `div` for a link he wants to style as a button.

Comment: Yes, of course, you are absolutely correct. But since he was asking about centering the text, my answer is not incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're using the wrong property. In flexbox, `justify-content` property is used to align items on the main axis (horizontally), while the `align-items` property is used to align items on the cross axis (vertically). So from your styling, you're only aligning the items on the main axis, and not on the cross axis as well.

To fix the issue you're having, you just need to add the `align-items: center` property to your `.subscribe-btn` style class. Your updated code should look like this below:

```
.subscribe-btn {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0.5em;
    width: 290px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#4968b0, #3d559e);
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-style: outset;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; // aligns item on the cross axis (vertically)
    text-align: center;
}
```

You can read more here [MDN documentation on Aligning items in a flexbox container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Aligning_items_in_a_flex_container). Let me know if it works.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add align-items:center;

```css
.subscribe-btn {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0.5em;
  width: 290px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#4968b0, #3d559e);
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: outset;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.subscribe-btn a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
  <div class="subscribe-btn">
    <a href="https://www.bridgetodata.org/register">Subscribe to [WEBSITE NAME]</a>
</div>
```

Comment: He needs to not be using a `div` for a button in the first place. That is the first thing he needs to fix.

Comment: I think because it is a duplicated question. I did not downvote the answers, my own answer has -2 and it was thoughtful and fleshed out. I think just because it is a duplicate question. I guess to discourage people from answering duplicates. That being said, there is no reason for him to set up the div in this way, even if he is adding things later. The div has the button styling on it and then there is an <a> element inside of that. This is a problem not just for semantics, but also potentially for the click box. No reason to do a button or link like that, it goes against spec.

Comment: I think in that case it would be better to filter questions from the beginning

Answer (score -2):

Please add:

```css
.subscribe-btn{
/*Other attributes*/
align-items:center;
}
```